# How can I quickly up-cast object[,] into double[,]?

Tags: c#, vb.net, office-interop

I using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` I get returned a 2D array of type `object[,]` which contains `double` for elements. Note that the index lower bound is `1` instead of the default `0`, but I can deal with that easily.

How can *nicely* convert the array into `double[,]` using .NET 3.5. (by nicely I mean concise, or compact).

Note that

```
double[] values_2 = values.Cast<double>().ToArray();
```

does work, but it flattens by array into a 1D structure.

Comment: There's no "quick" way to do it. You have to copy all the data into a new array if that's what you want.

Comment: I was afraid of that. What about `.NET 4.0` ?  Will there ever be a type safe way of doing Office Interop?

Comment: quickly as in "no cpu" or quickly as in "a-one-line-statement"

Comment: You can probably do it in one line with linq, but its not going to be any faster in terms of computation power.

Comment: I should add that the two different arrays (2D array of `double` and 2D array of `object` with 1-based indices) are very different objects. There's no way to cast between them.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
object[,] src = new object[2, 3];

// Initialize src with test doubles.
src[0, 0] = 1.0;
src[0, 1] = 2.0;
src[0, 2] = 3.0;
src[1, 0] = 4.0;
src[1, 1] = 5.0;
src[1, 2] = 6.0;

double[,] dst = new double[src.GetLength(0), src.GetLength(1)];
Array.Copy(src, dst, src.Length);
```

Comment: This will work great because I can use it in reverse also, to put the values back into Excel. Forget LINQ, go with Dotnet v1.0 good old static functions of `Array`.

Comment: This was crazy fast compared to doing it manually with a for loop.. Go old skool .Net tricks!

Comment: Does it work for int[,] to ushort[,] as well of there is no overflow?

Comment: Note that in VB.NET you will need to adjust the result of GetLength before passing it to the constructor since the VB.NET sized array initializer doesn't take length but the maximum index.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't say that there is one way that's faster than another so long as you don't do anything stupid. I'd say that, if you can, cast them when you access them rather than up front. Of course this depends on how you intend to access them. If you're going to index into the array more than once then the cost of unboxing might start to get too much. If you're only scanning the array once, then cast as you go.

Answer (score 3):

This should work in most cases, but may throw an exception if you don't assign a conversion delegate.

```
public static TResult[,] Convert<TSource, TResult>(
    this TSource[,] array, Func<TSource, TResult> conversion = null) {

        if(array == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("array");

        if (conversion == null) {
            var resultType = typeof(TResult);
            conversion = source => (TResult)System.Convert.ChangeType(source, resultType);
        }

        var width = array.GetLength(1);
        var height = array.GetLength(0);
        var result = new TResult[height, width]; 

        for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i)
            for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j)
                result[i, j] = conversion(array[i, j]);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but doing an element by element conversion is not very efficient and definitely not a _nice_ solution. Good to have this here for posterity though.

Comment: I agree, it's a bit ugly, but should be useful in a wider range of circumstances than just dealing with Excel's object arrays.  The default behavior is certainly slow, but passing in an appropriate delegate can speed things up a lot.

Comment: The accepted solution does the job just fine, without an hand holding.

Answer (score 2):

```
Array.Copy(src, dst, src.Length);
```

This code will get an error if any of the `value` in ***src*** is null.

Since in the above code ***src*** has a defined value it works fine.

If the value of ***src*** is dynamically set, and unfortunately if any of the value is null, the above code will not work because the `value` wont be copied successfully.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems here.

First, since `double` is not a reference type it must be boxed to be stored in an object[], so the only way to get to the values is to unbox the values into a double[] (copy copy).

The other problem is that in C#, arrays are covariant but not contravariant, you can assign an array to a reference of a more-derived type, not not to one of a less-derived type.

```
string[] strings = new string[10];
object[] objects = strings; // OK, covariant
string[] strings2 = objects; // not OK, contravariant
objects[0] = 10; // Compiles fine, runtime ArrayTypeMismatchException!
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to add a helpful thought about reading arrays in from Excel via interop. I always use a custom class (code below) to force Excel to hand over what looks like a base-zero array, to keep my wider code from getting confused between bases.

In my example below, I actually use two constructors, to catch the special case where it is a single-cell Range being read in from Excel, because Excel is annoying and does not hand over an array in this case. This way, the ExcelData class creates a 1-by-1 array so the rest of your code can not break when a single cell is encountered!

```cs
public class ExcelData
{   // This class wraps an Excel range read - it will either be created by:
    // 1. An object[,] base-1 array from Excel stored as excelData[1..rows,1..cols]
    // 2. An object scalar value from Excel stored as _excelData[0,0]
    // In either case, the 'this' identifier allows access as if it was a base-0 array.
    private object[,] _excelData;
    private bool _baseZero;
    public ExcelData(object[,] excelData)
    { // Constructor for usual case of receiving a base-1 object[,] from Excel
        this._excelData = excelData;
        this._baseZero = false;
    }
    public ExcelData(object excelData)
    { // Constructor for special case where only single value is returned
        this._excelData = new object[1,1];
        this._excelData[0, 0] = excelData;
        this._baseZero = true;
    }
    public object this[int x, int y]
    { // Returns the correct element on a zero-basis
        get
        {
            if (this._baseZero)
            { return this._excelData[x, y]; }
            else
            { return this._excelData[x + 1, y + 1]; }
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._baseZero)
            { this._excelData[x, y] = value; }
            else
            { this._excelData[x + 1, y + 1] = value; }
        }
    }
    public int RowCount { get { return _excelData.GetLength(0); } }
    public int ColCount { get { return _excelData.GetLength(1); } }
}
```

You could, of course, modify the above to explicitly add Properties to read out data in a specific Type if you wished. That way you can store the data as an object[*,*] like Excel gives you (and expects back) but treat it like a different kind of array when retrieving (or updating) data using Get/Set methods.

Comment: Nice workaround to the edge case where a range contains a single cell. :-)