# interop.excel convert Range Object(,) to Double(,)

Tags: vb.net, excel-interop

I have a Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range Object obtained as shown:

```
Dim maxRow As Integer = currentSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
currentSheet.Range("A2").Resize(maxRow-1, 2).Value
```

and I'm trying to convert that to a 2 dimensional array of doubles, but if I do:

```
Dim arrayData(,) As Double = currentSheet.Range("A2").Resize(maxRow - 1, 2).Value
```

I get the following error:

> Additional information: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Object[,]' to type 'System.Double[,]'.

Is there a simple way to obtain the data from a spreadsheet as an array of doubles? I could loop over each element in the array, but it seems like that shouldn't be necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Array.Copy()`

```
Dim arrayData(,) As Double
Dim objData(,) As Object = currentSheet.Range("A2").Resize(maxRow - 1, 2).Value
Array.Copy(objData, arrayData, objData.Length)
```

By the way I found this by putting `convert 2d object double` into a search engine...
[How can I quickly up-cast object[,] into double[,]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083565/how-can-i-quickly-up-cast-object-into-double)

**Edit**

I just tried it on my own Excel sheet and it works. One thing I should add is that I needed to specify the bounds of the destination array when dimensioning it.

```
'Dim objData(,) As Object = xlSheet.Range("C6:E14").Value ' either way works
Dim objData(,) As Object = xlSheet.Range("C6").Resize(9, 3).Value
Dim dblData(objData.GetUpperBound(0) - 1, objData.GetUpperBound(1) - 1) As Double
Array.Copy(objData, dblData, objData.Length)
```

Can you inspect your `Object(,)` at runtime to make sure there is data inside it? Also, everything needs to be castable to `Double`.

Comment: Well, apparently you are better at searching than I am because I spent at least 4 hours without finding anything that actually worked.

Comment: Upon further investigation I have discovered that while this will compile, it does not copy the data as intended. Many values at the end of the array are 0 when they should not be. In fact, the only values that I was able to find that were correct are arrayData(0,0) and arrayData(0,1).

Comment: I am specifying the bounds of my destination array, and I have verified that all my data is castable to Double. I have successfully copied the data into a 2D array of doubles by using nested for loops and `Double.Parse()` but for some reason when switching back to this method I still have some cells that are filled with '0' instead of the actual values, and the rest (except the first 2) are wrong. My array of Object is apparently 1 indexed and my array of Double is 0 indexed, could this be causing the problem?

Comment: Maybe you have some hidden cells? Otherwise I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I think I'm going to go with the nested loops anyway as there are now some calculations I want to do on each element

Answer (score -1):

This is a C# sample, but you shouldn't have problems converting it to vb.

```
object[,] arrWks = (object[,])enuWorksheet.UsedRange.get_Value(XLS.XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault);
```

So int your case, instead of `.Value`, use `get_Value` method.

Then when iterating through array, remember to check for nulls:

```
object objKom = arrWks[intRow, intCol];
string strKom = objKom == null ? "" : objKom.ToString();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: `but you shouldn't have problems converting it to vb` - then you shouldn't either.