# Converting Object [,] to String[,]

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an `object[,]` array *(with for example some integers in it)* to a `string[,]` array. I wrote this piece of code but Visual Studio gives me an error saying:

> Cannot implicitly convert `String[]` to `String[,]`.

What argument should I give to the `Array.ConvertAll` function? Thanks a lot.

```
object[,] input = GetSelectedRange();

string[,] dst = Array.ConvertAll<object[,], string[,]>(
    input, 
    x => x.ToString()
);
```

Comment: @keyboardP but the OP has `ToString`...

Comment: Yep tried the copy method but get an error because my input contains strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would have been a lot easier if your item is `object[][]` rather than `object[,]`. But for `object[,]`, why not using traditional method?

```
object[,] input = GetSelectedRange();
string[,] output = new string[input.GetLength(0), input.GetLength(1)];
for (int i = 0; i < input.GetLength(0); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < input.GetLength(1); ++j)
        output[i, j] = input[i, j]?.ToString(); //give additional ?. to check if your input is null
```

Suggestion by [Olivier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880990/olivier-jacot-descombes): to check if your input is null by using C#6 syntax `?.`

Or, if you use lower version, use ternary operator:

```
object[,] input = GetSelectedRange();
string[,] output = new string[input.GetLength(0), input.GetLength(1)];
for (int i = 0; i < input.GetLength(0); ++i)
    for (int j = 0; j < input.GetLength(1); ++j)
        output[i, j] = input[i, j] == null ? null input[i, j].ToString();
```

Comment: Starting with C# 6.0: `output[i, j] = input[i, j]?.ToString();` makes it a little bit safer. (Note the `?.`)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes ah, C# 6! Why not? ;)

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes updated to check if the input is null

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes If the inputs are not expected to contain `null` (as indicated by the OP's attempt to call `.ToString()` unconditionally), I disagree that it's "safer". It silently lets the application continue with corrupted state, which is sure to blow up later.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I implemented this and get an Index Out of Range Exception. I did this on a 2x2 array filled with integers, without null values...

Comment: Yes , but it doesn't hurt to consider the conversion of a slightly more general point of view.

Comment: @AndrévanderHeijden I use the input length to generate the matrix dimension, there shouldn't be issue. Which one gets the Index Out of Range Exception?

Comment: Have you used `<=` instead of `<`? Debug!

Comment: Ah, I see it. Strangely enough the object[,] that is returned from GetSelectedRange() starts its indexing at 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @AndrévanderHeijden: What is the source of the array? If it's coming from VB, arrays there are one-based so must be accessed accordingly.

Comment: Yep it's an Excel range, adapted the code and it works now. @Ian: Thanks a lot my friend!

Comment: @AndrévanderHeijden No problem! ;) glad that you can fix your issue!

Answer (score 3):

`Array.ConvertAll()` only handles one-dimensional arrays.  The input is expected to be an array of the input type and produces an array of the output type.  The converter is expecting something that can convert `object[,]` -> `string[,]`.

Multi-dimensional arrays do not have generic convert method, you would have to do it by hand.  You could do something like this:

```
public TOutput[,] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[,] input, Func<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    var length0 = input.GetLength(0);
    var length1 = input.GetLength(1);
    var result = new TOutput[length0, length1];
    for (var i = 0; i < length0; ++i)
    for (var j = 0; j < length1; ++j)
        result[i, j] = converter(input[i, j]);
    return result;
}
```

Then you could do this to do the conversion:

```
var input = GetSelectedRange();
var converted = ConvertAll(input, x => x.ToString());
```

---

If it's possible that the source array is not 0-based, some adjustments would need to be made to handle the changed bounds.

```
public TOutput[,] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[,] input, Func<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    var lengths = new[] { input.GetLength(0), input.GetLength(1) };
    var lowers = new[] { input.GetLowerBound(0), input.GetLowerBound(1) };
    var uppers = new[] { input.GetUpperBound(0), input.GetUpperBound(1) };
    var result = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(TOutput), lengths, lowers) as TOutput[,];
    for (int i = lowers[0], il = uppers[0]; i <= il; ++i)
    for (int j = lowers[1], jl = uppers[1]; j <= jl; ++j)
            result[i, j] = converter(input[i, j]);
    return result;
}
```

---

For a general purpose converter that can handle all arrays, this could be used.

```
public Array ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(Array input, Func<TInput, TOutput> converter)
{
    var rank = input.Rank;
    var lengths = Enumerable.Range(0, rank).Select(i => input.GetLength(i)).ToArray();
    var lowerBounds = Enumerable.Range(0, rank).Select(i => input.GetLowerBound(i)).ToArray();
    var upperBounds = Enumerable.Range(0, rank).Select(i => input.GetUpperBound(i));
    var output = Array.CreateInstance(typeof(TOutput), lengths, lowerBounds);
    ConvertRank(input, converter, output, new int[0], lowerBounds.Zip(upperBounds, Tuple.Create).ToArray());
    return output;
}

private void ConvertRank<TInput, TOutput>(Array input, Func<TInput, TOutput> converter, Array output, int[] indices, Tuple<int, int>[] bounds)
{
    if (!bounds.Any())
    {
        var value = input.GetValue(indices);
        var convertedValue = converter((TInput)value);
        output.SetValue(convertedValue, indices);
    }
    else
    {
        var start = bounds[0].Item1;
        var end = bounds[0].Item2;
        var tail = bounds.Skip(1).ToArray();
        for (var i = start; i <= end; i++)
            ConvertRank(input, converter, output, indices.Concat(new[] { i }).ToArray(), tail);
    }
}
```

You'll just need to cast back the array to the expected type (since the rank could not be expressed).

```
object[,,] input = GetSome3dObjectArray();
var converted = ConvertAll(input, (object x) => x.ToString()) as string[,,];
```

If you wanted some strong typing, you could create the appropriate overloads for the types you want to support.

```
public TOutput[,] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[,] input, Func<TInput, TOutput> converter) =>
    ConvertAll((Array)input, converter) as TOutput[,];
public TOutput[,,] ConvertAll<TInput, TOutput>(TInput[,,] input, Func<TInput, TOutput> converter) =>
    ConvertAll((Array)input, converter) as TOutput[,,];
```

Answer (score 0):

From: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5083690/380384

```
object[,] src = new object[2, 3];

// Initialize src with test strings.
src[0, 0] = "aa";
src[0, 1] = "ab";
src[0, 2] = "ac";
src[1, 0] = "ba";
src[1, 1] = "bb";
src[1, 2] = "bc";

string[,] dst = new string[src.GetLength(0), src.GetLength(1)];
Array.Copy(src, dst, src.Length);
```

Note that this not converting but re-casting. It works if the `object` elements are really `string` elements (like what comes from a `Excel` worksheet).