# from multiple-dimension array double, to int

Tags: c#

As the title says, I would like to know if there is a simple way to convert a multiple dimension array of `double` numbers to the same array, but in `int` numbers.

Of course we could have two(or more) `for` loops going to each number and convert them, but I was wondering if there is a simple method to do it? :)

(By the way I am truly sorry if this question has already been asked a lot, but I didn't find any answer!)

Edit: As I lack a lot of informations:
I have for example

```
double[,] tab1 = {{3.42,1.6523,42.42142},{42.124,932.241, 9.421}};
int[,] tab2;
```

And I would like to have at the end

```
tab2 = {{3,1,42}{42,932,9}}
```

Right now the code I have to do this is

```
for(int i=0; i<tab1.GetLength(0); i++){
    for (int j=0; j<tab1.GetLength(1); j++) {
        tab2[i,j] = (int)tab1[i,j];
    }
}
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083565/how-can-i-quickly-up-cast-object-into-double

Comment: Apparently the solution they offer there doesn't work in this case

Comment: The main solution wouldn't work, but the extension method shown could be used to handle this. However, this does reduce down to just running nested loops.

Answer (score 3):

Well considering it's a two dimensional array, you can do it using a single `for` loop and using [`Array.ConvertAll()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53(v=vs.110).aspx) method. See an example below. hope gives a pointer

```
int[] convertedArray = Array.ConvertAll(myDoubleArray, x => (int)x);
```