# Get Values out of "System.Object[,]" c#

Tags: c#, arrays, object

I collect a data out of a excel sheet like this (using Interop Excel):

```
var tmp = WorkSheet.Range["G2", "AG2"].Value2;
```

Now my problem is that I can't get to the data because the type of tmp is `object {object[,]}`. How can i get access to the data?

[image]

Comment: What about `Convert.ToDouble(tmp[r, c])` where `r` and `c` are the row and column indices that you want to access?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I quickly up-cast object\[,\] into double\[,\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083565/how-can-i-quickly-up-cast-object-into-double)

Comment: @Youssef13 If i try something like this: ` var tmp2 = Convert.ToDouble(tmp[r, c]); ` i got an error CS0021

Comment: Please copy/paste the error message text.

Comment: Indexing with [] cannot be applied to an expression of the type "object". CS0021

Comment: Consider casting `tmp` to `object[,]` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your image from the debugger all the values are in double, so you can safely cast to double.

```
var tmp = (object[,])WorkSheet.Range["G2", "AG2"].Value2;
// Create a copy of the array
double[,] doubles = new double[tmp.GetLength(0), tmp.GetLength(1)];
for (int x = 0; x < tmp.GetLength(0); x++)
{
    for (int y = 0; y < tmp.GetLength(1); y++)
    {
        doubles[x, y] = (double)tmp[x, y];
    }
}
// Or inline
double value = (double)tmp[x,y]
```

Comment: Array.Copy may work well and is less to type than a loop.

`var doubles = new double[tmp.GetLength(0), tmp.GetLength(1)];`

`Array.Copy(tmp, doubles, tmp.Length);`

Comment: @Youssef13  If i try to use your code, i got a error CS1061 "object" does not contain a definition for "GetLength".

Comment: @Lars Consider casting `tmp` to `object[,]` first.