# How do I cast an object[*,*] directly into a string[*,*] in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I am updating an Excel add-in (XLL) that needs to process the UsedRange on each Excel sheet of a Workbook. For performance and stability reasons, I have switched from a previous behaviour of looping over each Range object in the UsedRange area, to instead reading in the UsedRange.Formula and UsedRange.Value2 as object[*,*] arrays. This new approach is still fairly slow, I suspect because of the 'bulkiness' of the object[*,*] arrays.

My code needs to inspect each Formula as the primary activity in a cell-by-cell loop (implemented as a row, column nested loop) and only needs to check the Value2 data if certain conditions are met. Therefore I am trying to see how I might map the UsedRange.Formula array directly to a string[*,*] array, because I think this will be significantly faster to loop over?

I currently use something like:

```cs
object[,] formulas = (object[,])ws.UsedRange.Formula;
int row_count = formulas.GetUpperBound(0);
int col_count = formulas.GetUpperBound(1);
```

Then I loop over the formulas array doing what I need to do. But Excel Formula data is always a string (or empty string), so it should be pretty straight forward to make a string[*,*]. This code does not work, however:

```cs
string[,] formulas_str = (string[,])formulas;
```

Is it possible to do an array-wise cast to string[*,*] like I want to do here? If I have to do it element-by-element, then I gain nothing from doing it.

Comment: you can't really do it without tricks.
But if you know the contents are strings, what stops you from casting from `object` to `string` when needed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I quickly up-cast object\[,\] into double\[,\]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5083565/how-can-i-quickly-up-cast-object-into-double)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly casting an object[,] array to a string[,] array in C# is not supported because the runtime cannot guarantee that all objects in the array are strings. Even though Excel formulas are strings, when you retrieve them through the UsedRange.Formula, they come as an array of objects due to the nature of the COM interface and to accommodate for the possibility that different types of data could be contained within the range.

If you must convert the array to string[,] for your specific use case, doing so with minimal overhead is key. Unfortunately, you have to iterate through the array:

```
object[,] formulas = (object[,])ws.UsedRange.Formula;
int rows = formulas.GetUpperBound(0) + 1; // Bounds are zero-based
int cols = formulas.GetUpperBound(1) + 1;
string[,] formulasStr = new string[rows, cols];

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
        // Safely cast each object to a string, handling possible null values
        formulasStr[i, j] = formulas[i, j]?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfect - this is a really clear explanation, thank you.
It actually turns out there was some unintended behaviour in my code (it was doing something very slow that should only apply to <<1% of the cells to almost all of them!), so actually cycling the object[,] was fine for now. This answer saved me wasting time looking for a way to do the impossible though, so thanks again!

Answer (score -2):

You can do it through struct layout:

```
var a = new object[,]{{"abcd", null, null}};
Console.WriteLine(Caster.Cast(a)[0,0]);    //abcd
Console.WriteLine(Caster.Cast(a)[0,0][1]); //b

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct Caster
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public object[,] Input;
    [FieldOffset(0)] public string[,] Output;
    
    public static string[,] Cast(object[,] input)
    {
        var tmp = new Caster
        {
            Input = input
        };
        return tmp.Output;
    }
}
```

**PS** This is dark magic, usage will give you STDs